# why does urllib.urlopen throw an exception in python 3?

Tags: python

Why is the following python code throwing an exception?

```
import urllib

htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
print (htmltext)
```

*Traceback*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dhfur/Desktop/webcrawl1.py", line 3, in <module>
    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: because you are using python2 code, its `import urllib.request`

Comment: A kind reminder: urllib is primeval, use `requests`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the functionality was moved to the [`urllib.request` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import urllib.request

htmlfile=urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")
```

A whole lot of things were moved in Python 3 from their former Python 2 locations. The Python 2 documentation usually names the new location; the [`urllib` documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) is no exception:

> **Note**: The `urllib` module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to `urllib.request`, `urllib.parse`, and `urllib.error`. The *2to3* tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3. Also note that the `urllib.request.urlopen()` function in Python 3 is equivalent to `urllib2.urlopen()` and that `urllib.urlopen()` has been removed.

The [Python 3 documentation page for `urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) names all new modules under the namespace.

Comment: Nice tip about **Note**; I hadn't noticed that before, thanks.